# Why SQL Alchemy async engine does not persist database setting change

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update the timezone of a database using SQLAlchemy with psycopg async driver. However, the timezone is not reflected as being changed in the code, even though in the database it looks like is changed, code bellow and its output.

At this point the database timezone is set to Europe/Bucharest and I want to change it to Europe/Amsterdam.

```
import asyncio
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import (
    create_async_engine,
    AsyncSession,
)


db_uri = "postgresql+psycopg://bigbrother:BigBrother0906!!@10.190.20.72:5432/bigbrother"
db_engine = create_async_engine(db_uri, max_overflow=1, pool_size=2)


@asynccontextmanager
async def db_session_manager(a_db_engine):
    session = sessionmaker(a_db_engine, expire_on_commit=False, class_=AsyncSession)()
    try:
        yield session
        await session.commit()
    except Exception as ex:
        await session.rollback()
        raise ex
    finally:
        await session.close()


async def update_timezone():
    async with db_session_manager(db_engine) as session:
        await session.execute(
            text(
                """
            ALTER DATABASE "bigbrother"
            SET timezone TO 'Europe/Amsterdam'
        """
            )
        )


async def get_timezone():
    async with db_session_manager(db_engine) as session:
        current_timezone = (
            (
                await session.execute(
                    text(
                        """
                SELECT
                    name, abbrev, utc_offset, is_dst
                FROM pg_timezone_names
                WHERE name = current_setting('TIMEZONE')
            """
                    )
                )
            )
            .mappings()
            .one()
        )
        print(current_timezone)


print("timezone before")
asyncio.run(get_timezone())
asyncio.run(update_timezone())
print("timezone after update")
asyncio.run(get_timezone())
```

And this code is providing the following output:

timezone before
{'name': 'Europe/Bucharest', 'abbrev': 'EEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), 'is_dst': True}
timezone after update
{'name': 'Europe/Bucharest', 'abbrev': 'EEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), 'is_dst': True}

This output reflects that the engine still sees the old timezone, but If I check the database properties, the timezone seems change, which makes me think that this is related to caching.

If I run it again, thus recreating the engine, it provides the following output:

timezone before
{'name': 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'abbrev': 'CEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'is_dst': True}
timezone after update
{'name': 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'abbrev': 'CEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'is_dst': True}

What I would like to do is to get the timezone changed without recreating the engine, or remove the caching from the engine or refresh the engine somehow so it sees my modification. That would mean that, if the current database timezone is Europe/Bucharest and the desired one is Europe/Amsterdam, I want my code to provide the following output:

timezone before
{'name': 'Europe/Bucharest', 'abbrev': 'EEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), 'is_dst': True}
timezone after update
{'name': 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'abbrev': 'CEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'is_dst': True}

Versions that I use:
python==3.8.13 backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1 greenlet==2.0.2 pendulum==2.1.2 psycopg==3.1.9 python-dateutil==2.8.2 pytzdata==2020.1 six==1.16.0 SQLAlchemy==2.0.19 typing_extensions==4.7.1

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to-do with sqlalchemy, nor with asyncio, that's how postgresql works. Even if you'll do this in `psql` session, you'll get the same result. Here's `psql` sample session that should explain:

```sql
> select current_setting('timezone'); -- check current session timezone
 Europe/Kiev

> select setrole, setconfig from pg_db_role_setting 
  inner join pg_database on pg_database.oid = pg_db_role_setting.setdatabase
  where pg_database.datname = 'testing'; -- select default database settings

setrole |          setconfig          
---------+-----------------------------
       0 | {TimeZone=Europe/Kiev}


> alter database testing set timezone to 'Europe/Amsterdam'; -- alter database timzone

> select current_setting('timezone'); -- current session timezone is still the same
 Europe/Kiev

> select setrole, setconfig from pg_db_role_setting 
  inner join pg_database on pg_database.oid = pg_db_role_setting.setdatabase
  where pg_database.datname = 'testing'; -- default database settings have changed

 setrole |          setconfig          
---------+-----------------------------
       0 | {TimeZone=Europe/Amsterdam}
```

As you can see, doing `alter database <DB> set timezone` changes default database parameters and not the current one. When you create a new session, it uses these default values, so your new session has a different value for the `timezone`. The easiest fix would be to change current values as well with `set`, like this:

```sql
> select current_setting('TIMEZONE');
Europe/Kiev
> set timezone to 'Europe/Amsterdam';
> select current_setting('TIMEZONE');
 Europe/Amsterdam
```

so you need to update `update_timezone` function and add `set timezone to 'Europe/Amsterdam'`, and the result of the script would be like this:

```
timezone before
{'name': 'Europe/Kiev', 'abbrev': 'EEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800), 'is_dst': True}
timezone after update
{'name': 'Europe/Amsterdam', 'abbrev': 'CEST', 'utc_offset': datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200), 'is_dst': True}
```

However, this is **most likely not what you want to do**,  since this will change `timezone` only in one connection (that did `set timezone`), since `sqlalchemy` uses connection pooling, another connection (that could exist), will still have another value for `timezone`.

One option would be just executing `set timezone to 'Europe/Amsterdam'` as the first SQL expression that you execute, in that case all connections will have this timezone from the start.

Another option, is to provide timezone in a `db_uri`:

```py
db_uri = "postgresql+psycopg://bigbrother:BigBrother0906!!@10.190.20.72:5432/bigbrother?options=-c TIMEZONE=Europe/Amsterdam"
```

You can use [this URL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) in order to check what options are available.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Is really helpful